# Software to backup recently modified files in few directories

Tags: mac, applications, backup

I used to use this software which used to pick recently modified files from a configurable set of directories and back it up (into another synced folder inside Dropbox).

The purpose is to recover files which were not backed up into Time Machine.

My SSD crashed and I can no longer find the software. Is there a similar software that you are using to fulfil the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

[QuickSand](http://www.zibity.com/quicksand.html) was the software I was searching for.